# Protected constructor on parent and inherited default one not protected

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, default

I have a question about default constructor on inherited class when the parent one is protected, in my mind the child class will have a default one protected too, but it's not the case.

Is there's a way to force the default constructor to be protected other than force it on child class ?

C++11 - gcc version 5.3.1 20151219 (Debian 5.3.1-4).

```
int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) 
{
    using namespace std;

    class A
    {
     public:
       static std::shared_ptr<A> CreateInstance ()
       { 
           A * pInstance { new A };

           return { pInstance, []( A * pInstance )
           {
           delete pInstance;
           }};
       };

     protected:
       A () = default;
       ~A () = default;
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    };

    B b; // It's work !

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help,

WCdr

Comment: No. A base class generally can't "force" derived classes to do anything.

Comment: @WCdr Did you really mean to ask if there's a way to prevent B from being directly instantiable?

Answer (score 2):

No, a derived class' automatically-generated default constructor will still be public even if the base class constructor is protected.

There are two ways (I can think of) to prevent derived class B from being directly instantiable:

### 1. Remove the default constructor in class A

This can be accomplished by providing a constructor that takes a dummy argument:

```
class A
{
 public:
   // ...

 protected:
   A (int) {}
};

class B : public A
{
};

B b; // error: B::B()' is implicitly deleted because the
     // default definition would be ill-formed
```

Instantiating B will fail, because B's automatically-generated default constructor will attempt to use A's default constructor, which does not exist.

But this is easily circumvented:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
  B() : A(0) {}
}

B b; // works
```

### 2. Force the derived class' constructor to be protected

```
class B
{
  // ...

protected:
  B() = default;
}
```

---

Option (2) will be the least surprising to others reading your code, and is the option that I recommend. Anyone familiar with static `createFoo` factory functions will understand why the constructor is made private or protected.

---

**EDIT**

When using static `create` factory functions in a class hierarchy, the common idiom is for derived classes to also provide static `create` factory functions, and make their constructor private or protected.

Derived classes should not use the `create` factory function of the base class. They should invoke base class constructor, either implicitly or explicitly.

```
class Base
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<Base> create()
    {
        return shared_ptr<Base>(new Base);
    }

protected:
    Base() {...}
};

class Derived
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<Derived> create()
    {
        return shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived);
    }

protected:
    Derived() {...} // Implicitly calls base class default constructor
};

// Usage
auto b = Base::create();
auto d = Derived::create();
```